# Friend got his public IP address grabbed and is paranoid. What should I tell him to do?

Tags: security

So let me recap what has happend, My friend was playing rust and some dude gave him a shady link saying it was a link to his discord server. On his pc he said he pressed a link and it brought him to a blank page for a couple seconds then forward him to the discord server so obviously something was up with that link. This is the link he sent: https://leancoding.co/O3V92L Then after a couple minutes the dude who sent him the link said "Idiot I just grabbed ur IP" and so my friend thought nothing much of it until his router just crashed he said and he could connect to it but he wasnt getting any connection to the internet and neither could his sister's phone or laptop. Him realizing that it might of been this dude of his he unplugged the router. Then thats when he contacted me asking what he should do.

What I was planning on him doing was plugging in his router and connecting to his routers settings and checking to see if his firewall was on since he has xfinity like me and for some reason my firewall wasnt on when my internet got setup. So he tried plugging the router in and it started working initially like he could connect to the internet but then it just disconnected after maybe 3 minutes of being connected. Im thinking hes just getting DDoSed by this dude but he is really paranoid about it and he wants to find anything he can do to help his security. I obviously told him not to press on weird links like that again since I dont know why he pressed on it in the first place.

Comment: it's possible that this guy started a DDoS attack on him? in any case, just have him call his ISP and aks them to switch the IP.

Comment: also, idk where this question belong, but it certainly isn't stackoverflow.com , maybe superuser.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, routers have log files, if you can navigate to the log and read there, you may find what happened.

Then reset the router and change its password and close all ports, and turn off all unwanted services.

Check home router security checklist [here](https://routersecurity.org/checklist.php)